# DigestUtils.md5Hex() generates wrong hash value when passing String object

Tags: md5, kotlin

I'm trying to generate a md5 hash in Kotlin using the `DigestUtils` class from the `org.apache.commons.codec`. Here's the test code

```
@Test
fun md5Test(){

    val userPassword: String = "123"
    val md5Hash: String = "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70"

    assertEquals(md5Hash, DigestUtils.md5Hex(userPassword))
}
```

The problem is that when I run this test it fails and says that the generated md5 hash is **28c1a138574866e9c2e5a19dca9234ce**

But... when I pass the String value instead of the object

```
assertEquals(md5Hash, DigestUtils.md5Hex("123"))
```

The test passes without errors

Why this is happening?

Comment: Your example test passes for me.

Comment: @mfulton26 which version of kotlin are you using?

Comment: I'm using Kotlin 1.0.6.

Comment: Me too. Still not working. I'm using  library `commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10`

Comment: kotlin 1.1.4-2 doesn't have such problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete solution to get MD5 base64 hash:

```
fun getMd5Base64(encTarget: ByteArray): String? {
    val mdEnc: MessageDigest?
    try {
        mdEnc = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
        // Encryption algorithmy
        val md5Base16 = BigInteger(1, mdEnc.digest(encTarget))     // calculate md5 hash
        return Base64.encodeToString(md5Base16.toByteArray(), 16).trim()     // convert from base16 to base64 and remove the new line character
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: "Base64.encodeToString" shows unresolved reference, any suggestion?

Comment: @SARATHV You probably imported `java.util.Base64`. I used `android.util.Base64` class which you can find here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Base64.java#455

Answer (score 1):

This is the most simple and complete solution in kotlin:

```
val hashedStr = String.format("%032x", BigInteger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest("your string value".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))))
```